# Create a rectangle that's the result of the intersection between two rectangles

Tags: python, object

I'm trying to intersect two rectangles but I have no clue on how to do it.
I've done two classes which are point and color and they work fine. Now I'm trying to get this intersection done. That's the rectangle class i've wrote

```
class Rectangle:
def __init__(self,Point,width,lenght,Color):
    self.x = Point.x
    self.y = Point.y
    self.x1 = self.x + lenght
    self.y1 = self.y + width
    self.r = Color.r
    self.g = Color.g
    self.b = Color.b
    self.w = width
    self.l = lenght
```

And as far as I've tried the intersection function it didn't work. I tried something like this

```
def inter(self,r):
    if   ((self.x > r.x1) or (self.x1 < r.x) or (self.y > r.y1) or (self.y1 < r.y)):
        return None
    else:
        return Rectangle(Point(x,y),w,h,Color.mix(self,r))
```

Where i defined the `.mix` function into the color class. The input of this function is the existent rectangle `self` and another one rectangle that is `r`

As an example i can put this

```
A is the rectangle that starts at (100,40), width 70, lenght 40 and color (200,200,200) and
  B is the rectangle that starts at (120,90), width 40, lenght 60 and color (100,100,100)
  you will get a rectangle starting at (120,90), width 20, lenght 20 and color (150,150,150)
```

Keep in mind that the axis that I'm working on are placed like this

### 0 - - - - - X

### -

### -

Y

And i have to do everything using only standar libraries

Comment: What's wrong with your output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's wrong because it doesn't show the correct results , i get the right coords but i don't get the right width and lenght , i'm getting something like w:170 and l:50 if i remember well.

cricket_007 It might be a duplicate , but it's not the same language. I think I've put the tag "python" on this one but I might be wrong since i'm not so handy with this website.

Comment: Agreed. Basically, the key is the conditionals. And which `x,y,w,h` values to use depend always on the "inner" rectangle (if one exists). It's not just "this rectangle"s values

Comment: Precisely, it's not a duplicate at all... the linked questions asks for a algorithm to determine if two rectangles intercept.

Comment: The accepted answer there should be understood in any object oriented language pattern. Look at the if statements compared to yours

Comment: The questions are actually different.

Comment: Okay. This then - finds the intersection using min and max. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99565/simplest-way-to-calculate-the-intersect-area-of-two-rectangles

Comment: This question is actually closer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/19753280/679240

Answer (score 0):

This should be good to get you started. Please note that I haven't thoroughly tested it, so there may be bugs.

```
def inter(self,r):
    x = max(self.x, r.x)
    y = max(self.y, r.y)
    x1 = min(self.x1, r.x1)
    y1 = min(self.y1, r.y1)

    if x >= x1 or y >= y1:
        return None
    else:
        return Rectangle(Point(x,y), x1-x, y1-y, Color.mix(self,r))
```

See also:

- [C++ - Get the points of intersection from 2 rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19753280/679240)
- [Python - Intersection and difference of two rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25068722/679240)

Comment: It gives `none` instead of `(120,90), width 20, lenght 20 and color (150,150,150)`

Comment: Should have worked; try putting a breakpoint on the `if` statement to see what the values of `x`, `x1`, `y` and `y1` are.

Comment: I've tried it and i have no clue why the results are like this `x=100 y=140 x1=50 y1=80`
There should be `x=120 y=90 x1=140 y1=110`

Comment: That's really strange; if A and B start at `(100, 40)` and `(120, 40)`, respectively, then `x` should have been `120`, since `max(100, 120)` is `120`. I would recommend checking what are the values of `self.x`, `r.x`, `self.x1`, `r.x1`.

Comment: I feel dumb AF , i've inverted width with length when i did the addiction for x1 and y1. Now it works like a charm