# Create instances of class Rect from opencv 3 in Python

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I would like to know how I can get an opencv rect object by providing two Points. The c++ version provides this datastructre.

http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Rect.html

I cant find a way to instantiate rects in python. 
I tried `cv2.Rect(p1,p2)` but this method seems not be existent. 
Is it even possible?

Thanks in adavance :)

Comment: Nope doesn't seem to be provided. What do you want to do with a rectangle?

Comment: @barny I want to add it to a list to filter for duplicates.  Im using template matching on a image pyramid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for example at this tutorial face detection http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html and you'll see that in Python opencv bindings rectangles are tuples/lists of the four coordinates - the results of, for example, faceCascade.detectMultiScale is a list of these - basically, use normal Python capabilities to manage them.

I guess you'll have to write your own overlap/area/contains functions - not terribly diificult - or see other answers here, for example [Intersection and difference of two rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068538/intersection-and-difference-of-two-rectangles/25068722#25068722)

UPDATE - my bad, the rectangles returned by detectMultiScale are (x,y,w,h)