# How does python know to loop through the corners of a rectangle when it is not specified in the code?

Tags: python, opencv

Firstly apologies for the poorly worded title but didn't know how else to word it. I am new to python and opencv and am trying to make sense of some basic face detection code. There is one part of code that I am struggling to understand (perhaps lack of experience with python). The code is as follows:

```
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray,scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(10, 10))

for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
    cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0,255,0), 2)
```

The part I'm struggling to understand is how the for loop knows that ex, ey, ew and eh are the 4 corners of the rectangle? It feels to me like you should at least be saying:

```
for(ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes.coordinates
```

or something similar so it at least knows what to loop through. Sorry for my ignorance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because the library is designed such that `eyes` is already an iterable (e.g. a list), instead of having an attribute `coordinates` that is an iterable.

Comment: any comments for the downvotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all boils down to the question: **What exactly is a rectangle?**

From https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html and [Create instances of class Rect from opencv 3 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835145/create-instances-of-class-rect-from-opencv-3-in-python), we get to know that

> rectangles are tuples/lists of the four coordinates

and in python you can iterate a list of tuples as done in the loop

eg.

```
A = [('1', 1), ('2', 2)]
for (a, b) in A:
    print(a, type(a), b, type(b))

>> 1 <class 'str'> 1 <class 'int'>
>> 2 <class 'str'> 2 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: perfect answer thankyou! so i guess the order in which the coordinates is listed in a rectangle is important to know, which seemed to be difficult for me to find but i guess i was searching the wrong thing...

Comment: yes, you would like to refer the docs (for a general case it will depend on whether its a list of a data structure which is ordered or not)  but there is no doubt in your specific case that the order is fixed